# How to get device label in thingsboard rule chain?

Tags: thingsboard

How to get device label in thingsboard rule chain?.

I'm using originator node to get device ID and device Name and working well, but actual name is stored in device label (as there is no unique constrain) so need to get device label in rule chain to pass info to external service.

Anyone help on this would be grateful. thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I found, Label also can be accessed from Originator node. The source field to retrive label is 'label'. Thanks